# Pyvisa timing out with a Keysight power generator

Tags: python, ethernet, pyvisa

I am trying to read back the values that the Keysight generator has measured during the sampling period, but I keep getting a time out error:

```
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): 
Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

I am able to read in other data such as the IDN, so I dont think it is an error with the termination signal, I have been using this to get my commands from: http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/N6705-90001.pdf The part I was looking at is from page 162 to page 168. Here is my code the first part gets the IDN and reads off the voltage and current fine, it is the part after the measurements comment that seems to be not working. Thank you in advance.

```
#request info from keysight power generator
print(keysight.query("*IDN?"))
#set voltage, current and turn on otuput
keysight.write("VOLT 10, (@1)")
keysight.write("CURR 1, (@1)")
keysight.write("OUTP ON,(@1)")
#read current volt and curr
print(keysight.query_ascii_values("MEAS:VOLT? (@1)"))
print(keysight.query_ascii_values("MEAS:CURR? (@1)"))
#sets a limit on current and voltage
keysight.write("CURR:LIM .5, (@1)")
keysight.write("VOLT:LIM 30, (@1)")
#measurments
keysight.write("SENS:FUNC:VOLT ON,(@1)")
keysight.write("SENS:SWE:TINT RES1000,(@1)")
keysight.write("SENS:SWE:POIN 500,(@1)")
keysight.write("SENS:SWE:OFFS:POIN 10,(@1)")
keysight.write("INIT:ACQ (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("TRIG:ACQ (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 1, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 2, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 3, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 4, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 5, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("ABOR:ACQ(@1)")
print(keysight.query_ascii_values("FETC:VOLT:MAX?(@1)"))
time.sleep(.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was spacing problems, here is the code now:

```
#request info from keysight power generator
print(keysight.query("*IDN?"))
#set voltage, current and turn on otuput
keysight.write("*RST")
keysight.write("VOLT 3, (@1)")
keysight.write("CURR 1, (@1)")
keysight.write("OUTP ON,(@1)")
#read current volt and curr
print(keysight.query_ascii_values("MEAS:VOLT? (@1)"))
print(keysight.query_ascii_values("MEAS:CURR? (@1)"))
#sets a limit on current and voltage
keysight.write("CURR:PROT:STAT .5, (@1)")
keysight.write("VOLT:PROT 30, (@1)")
#measurments
keysight.write("SENS:FUNC:VOLT ON,(@1)")
#keysight.write("SENS:FUNC:CURR ON,(@1)")
keysight.write("SENS:SWE:TINT .001,(@1)")
keysight.write("SENS:SWE:POIN 5000,(@1)")
keysight.write("INIT:ACQ (@1)")
keysight.write("TRIG:ACQ (@1)")
keysight.write("VOLT 1, (@1)")
time.sleep(1.2)
keysight.write("VOLT 2, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 3, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 4, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
keysight.write("VOLT 5, (@1)")
time.sleep(1)
print "\n\n"
time.sleep(5)
x=keysight.query_ascii_values("FETC:ARR:VOLT? (@1)")
print x
```

Comment: In which line was the spacing problem ?

Comment: I dont remember, sorry it was a while ago, it might be this one keysight.write("SENS:SWE:TINT RES1000,(@1)")

Comment: Looks like your last meaningful line changed to include a space after the "?"

print(keysight.query_ascii_values("FETC:VOLT:MAX?(@1)")

Comment: @rajan maybe, I am sorry this was so long ago I don't remember anything about the code